# Why is Facebook Pixel firing the gtm.formSubmit event?

Tags: facebook, ajax, google-tag-manager, forms

I have a Google Tag Manger container that contains a Facebook Pixel injector tag and a regular form submission tag (with standard form submission trigger). However, when the submit button of a form is clicked (resulting in invalidation thus no submission), the `gtm.formSubmit` event is fired with the `elementUrl` as `'https://www.facebook.com/tr/'`. This event is captured by Tag Manager's standard Form Submission trigger, thus resulting in a false-positive form submission.

I had to confirm the Pixel as the cause by pausing the injector tag and testing. Of course the tag was not triggered.

I don't understand why the Pixel is firing this event on submit button click.

I would normally circumvent the issue by submitting the form via AJAX with a custom event name, but the nature of the site requires the forms navigate the user to a separate page. If I really can't prevent the Pixel from firing the event, I suppose I could use JavaScript to post via AJAX and manually navigate to a markup-stored URL, but I'd rather avoid that.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried setting up the default form submission trigger in a client's GMB container and was having the same problem. After a little digging around in Preview mode, I came up with the following solution:

Create a second Form Submission trigger and select "Some Forms" under "This trigger fires on". Then set it to fire on submissions where the Click URL contains "facebook". This sounds counter-intuitive at first, but you'll need to use this trigger as an 'Exception' on the Tag you *do* want to fire. Screenshot below (notice I used RegEx to also block Snapchat since that one is also triggering the gtm.formSubmit event. [image: Blocking trigger set up]

This works because if you look at the 'Variables' tab in Preview mode on the gtm.formSubmit event, it shows https://www.facebook.com/tr/ as the Click URL.

[image: Click URL]

Hopefully this makes sense and solves your issue as well!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, hopefully, I came here and saw the Casey's answer that makes me understand the error and how to solve it. But instead of creating a second form, I preferred to have only one trigger. So I followed the first steps that Casey showed us and setup the following inside "Some Forms" radio button:

```
Click URL | does not equal | https://www.facebook.com/tr/
```

This way my trigger is activated only in URLs that's not match the Facebook URL bug. And gladly this will solve the issue with only one trigger instead of two.